How do I display predicted class labels on the leaf nodes of an XGBoost decision tree?
I am working with an XGBoost classifier to predict types of exploitation. My dataset includes various features, and I have successfully trained a model. However, when I visualize the decision tree, the leaf nodes display float values instead of the predicted class labels (e.g., 'OnlyForcedLabor', 'OnlySexualExploitation', 'OnlyOtherExploit', 'BothSexualExploitAndForcedLabor').
I need help modifying the decision tree visualization to display the predicted class labels on the leaf nodes.
Here is the code I am using to train the model and visualize the tree:
CODE:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, to_graphviz
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load the data
df = pd.read_csv('CTDC_global_synthetic_data_v2024.csv', low_memory=False)

# Drop 'traffickMonths' and rows with missing values in critical columns
df = df.drop(columns=['traffickMonths'])
critical_columns = ['yearOfRegistration', 'gender', 'ageBroad', 'citizenship', 'CountryOfExploitation']
df = df.dropna(subset=critical_columns)

# Drop rows where gender is Trans/Transgender/NonConforming
df = df[df['gender'] != 'Trans/Transgender/NonConforming']

# Drop rows where all three indicators are missing
df = df.dropna(subset=['isSexualExploit', 'isForcedLabour', 'isOtherExploit'], how='all')

# Fill NaN in 'isSexualExploit', 'isForcedLabour', and 'isOtherExploit' with 0 to simplify checks
df[['isSexualExploit', 'isForcedLabour', 'isOtherExploit']] = df[['isSexualExploit', 'isForcedLabour', 'isOtherExploit']].fillna(0)

# Convert to integers (0 or 1)
df[['isSexualExploit', 'isForcedLabour', 'isOtherExploit']] = df[['isSexualExploit', 'isForcedLabour', 'isOtherExploit']].astype(int)

# Define target based on conditions
conditions = [
    (df['isForcedLabour'] == 1) & (df['isSexualExploit'] == 0) & (df['isOtherExploit'] == 0),
    (df['isForcedLabour'] == 0) & (df['isSexualExploit'] == 1) & (df['isOtherExploit'] == 0),
    (df['isForcedLabour'] == 0) & (df['isSexualExploit'] == 0) & (df['isOtherExploit'] == 1),
    (df['isForcedLabour'] == 1) & (df['isSexualExploit'] == 1) & (df['isOtherExploit'] == 0)
]
choices = [0, 1, 2, 3]  # Adjust target labels to integers

# Create the target column with integer labels
df['exploitType'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=-1)

# Filter out any rows where 'exploitType' is -1 if they do not meet any of the conditions
df = df[df['exploitType'] != -1]

# Encode the ordinal columns separately
ordinal_columns = ['yearOfRegistration', 'ageBroad']
label_encoders = {}

for column in ordinal_columns:
    le = LabelEncoder()
    df[column] = le.fit_transform(df[column])
    label_encoders[column] = le

# Extract unique values
unique_years = df['yearOfRegistration'].unique()
unique_ages = df['ageBroad'].unique()
unique_genders = df['gender'].unique()
unique_citizenships = df['citizenship'].unique()
unique_countries = df['CountryOfExploitation'].unique()

# Creating mapping dictionaries from unique values
year_mapping = {i: year for i, year in enumerate(label_encoders['yearOfRegistration'].classes_)}
age_mapping = {i: age for i, age in enumerate(label_encoders['ageBroad'].classes_)}
gender_mapping = {i: gender for i, gender in enumerate(unique_genders)}
citizenship_mapping = {i: citizenship for i, citizenship in enumerate(unique_citizenships)}
country_mapping = {i: country for i, country in enumerate(unique_countries)}

print("Year Mapping:", year_mapping)
print("Age Mapping:", age_mapping)
print("Gender Mapping:", gender_mapping)
print("Citizenship Mapping:", citizenship_mapping)
print("Country Mapping:", country_mapping)

# Convert necessary columns to category dtype for XGBoost
df['gender'] = df['gender'].astype('category')
df['citizenship'] = df['citizenship'].astype('category')
df['CountryOfExploitation'] = df['CountryOfExploitation'].astype('category')

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X = df[critical_columns]
y = df['exploitType']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Define the model
model = XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, eval_metric='mlogloss', enable_categorical=True, tree_method="hist")

# Train the model and evaluate with cross-validation
scores = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
print(f'Cross-validated accuracy: {scores.mean()}')

# Train the model on the entire training set
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Function to replace encoded values with actual names
def decode_tree(tree_text, year_mapping, gender_mapping, age_mapping, citizenship_mapping, country_mapping):
    for code, year in year_mapping.items():
        tree_text = tree_text.replace(f'yearOfRegistration<{code}', f'yearOfRegistration<{year}')
    for code, gender in gender_mapping.items():
        tree_text = tree_text.replace(f'gender<{code}', f'gender<{gender}')
    for code, age in age_mapping.items():
        tree_text = tree_text.replace(f'ageBroad<{code}', f'ageBroad<{age}')
    for code, citizenship in citizenship_mapping.items():
        tree_text = tree_text.replace(f'citizenship<{code}', f'citizenship<{citizenship}')
    for code, country in country_mapping.items():
        tree_text = tree_text.replace(f'CountryOfExploitation<{code}', f'CountryOfExploitation<{country}')
    return tree_text

# Convert the tree to a string and replace the codes
tree_text = model.get_booster().get_dump()[0]
tree_text_with_labels = decode_tree(tree_text, year_mapping, gender_mapping, age_mapping, citizenship_mapping, country_mapping)

# Save the modified tree text to a file
with open('temp_tree.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(tree_text_with_labels)

# Plot the decision tree
plt.figure(figsize=(60, 60))  # Adjust the figsize to make the plot larger
dot = to_graphviz(model, num_trees=0, rankdir='LR', 
                  condition_node_params={'shape': 'box', 'style': 'filled,rounded', 'fillcolor': '#78bceb', 'fontsize': '20'}, 
                  leaf_node_params={'shape': 'box', 'style': 'filled,rounded', 'fillcolor': '#e48038', 'fontsize': '20'}, 
                  yes_color='#0000FF', no_color='#FF0000')

dot.render('xgboost_tree', format='png')  # Save the tree as a PNG file

OUTPUT:
Year Mapping: {0: 2002.0, 1: 2003.0, 2: 2004.0, 3: 2005.0, 4: 2006.0, 5: 2007.0, 6: 2008.0, 7: 2009.0, 8: 2010.0, 9: 2011.0, 10: 2012.0, 11: 2013.0, 12: 2014.0, 13: 2015.0, 14: 2016.0, 15: 2017.0, 16: 2018.0, 17: 2019.0, 18: 2020.0, 19: 2021.0, 20: 2022.0} Age Mapping: {0: '0--8', 1: '09--17', 2: '18--20', 3: '21--23', 4: '24--26', 5: '27--29', 6: '30--38', 7: '39--47', 8: '48+'} Gender Mapping: {0: 'Man', 1: 'Woman'} Citizenship Mapping: {0: 'UKR', 1: 'KGZ', 2: 'USA', 3: 'BLR', 4: 'SLE', 5: 'BGD', 6: 'NGA', 7: 'MMR', 8: 'MEX', 9: 'GTM', 10: 'KHM', 11: 'ETH', 12: 'KEN', 13: 'HTI', 14: 'LKA', 15: 'SLV', 16: 'UGA', 17: 'SDN', 18: 'AFG', 19: 'PHL', 20: 'HND', 21: 'CHN', 22: 'UZB', 23: 'ROU', 24: 'MDA', 25: 'GHA', 26: 'IDN', 27: 'KAZ', 28: 'VNM', 29: 'BGR', 30: 'RUS', 31: 'TKM', 32: 'COL', 33: 'THA', 34: 'IND', 35: 'CIV', 36: 'TJK'} Country Mapping: {0: 'RUS', 1: 'KAZ', 2: 'USA', 3: 'POL', 4: 'LBN', 5: 'BGD', 6: 'LBY', 7: 'IDN', 8: 'MYS', 9: 'HTI', 10: 'JOR', 11: 'SAU', 12: 'UKR', 13: 'UGA', 14: 'OMN', 15: 'MLI', 16: 'AFG', 17: 'ARE', 18: 'MKD', 19: 'SRB', 20: 'BIH', 21: 'MDA', 22: 'GHA', 23: 'ROU', 24: 'TUR', 25: 'ITA', 26: 'QAT', 27: 'BLR', 28: 'CHN', 29: 'BGR', 30: 'GRC', 31: 'CZE', 32: 'ZAF', 33: 'MEX', 34: 'KHM', 35: 'TUN'}

Parameters: { "use_label_encoder" } are not used. 

Decision Tree Linked here
What did I try and what was I expecting?
I tried extracting the leaf values and mapping them to class labels, but the output was not as expected. All leaf values were mapped to "OnlyForcedLabor," which I know isn't correct. I need the leaf nodes in the decision tree to display the correct class labels based on the type of exploitation.
Attempted Code for mapping Leaf Values to Classes:
import json

# Extract the tree dump
booster = model.get_booster()
tree_dump = booster.get_dump(dump_format='json')[0]

# Parse the tree to extract leaf values and their corresponding predicted classes
tree = json.loads(tree_dump)

def extract_leaf_values(tree, leaf_values):
    if 'leaf' in tree:
        leaf_values.append(tree['leaf'])
    if 'children' in tree:
        for child in tree['children']:
            extract_leaf_values(child, leaf_values)

leaf_values = []
extract_leaf_values(tree, leaf_values)

# Print the extracted leaf values
print("Extracted leaf values:")
for value in leaf_values:
    print(f"Leaf value: {value}")
unique_leaf_values = list(set(leaf_values))
print("Unique leaf values:")
for value in unique_leaf_values:
    print(f"Leaf value: {value}")
from scipy.special import softmax

# Define the classes
class_labels = ['OnlyForcedLabor', 'OnlySexualExploitation', 'OnlyOtherExploit', 'BothSexualExploitAndForcedLabor']

# Map leaf values to class labels
def map_leaf_to_class(leaf_value, class_labels):
    # Convert the leaf value to a probability using softmax
    probabilities = softmax([leaf_value])
    # Map the highest probability to the corresponding class label
    predicted_class = class_labels[np.argmax(probabilities)]
    return predicted_class

# Create a dictionary to map unique leaf values to class labels
leaf_to_class_mapping = {value: map_leaf_to_class(value, class_labels) for value in unique_leaf_values}

# Print the mapping
print("Leaf to class mapping:")
for leaf, cls in leaf_to_class_mapping.items():
    print(f"Leaf value: {leaf} -> Class: {cls}")


OUTPUT:
Extracted leaf values:
Leaf value: 0.584565938
Leaf value: -0.164601773
Leaf value: -0.0962457359
Leaf value: 0.332342029
Leaf value: 0.0230769254
Leaf value: 0.594339609
Leaf value: 0.0591549315
Leaf value: 0.569387794
Leaf value: 0.597284317
Leaf value: -0.180000007
Leaf value: 0.581538498
Leaf value: 0.414893627
Leaf value: 0.473684251
Leaf value: 0.120000005
Leaf value: -0.185840726
Leaf value: -0.105882362
Leaf value: 0.197202817
Leaf value: -0.144827589
Leaf value: 0.547826111
Leaf value: -0.160714284
Leaf value: 0.120000005
Leaf value: 0.137142867
Leaf value: -0.169811323
Leaf value: 0.566037774
Leaf value: -0.195500389
Leaf value: 0.0352941193
Leaf value: -0.192814916
Leaf value: 0.0193548389
Leaf value: -0.139042303
Leaf value: -0.172117963
Leaf value: -0.0439024381
Leaf value: -0.145945951
Leaf value: 0.16097562
Leaf value: -0.144827589
Unique leaf values:
Leaf value: 0.584565938
Leaf value: -0.164601773
Leaf value: 0.332342029
Leaf value: 0.594339609
Leaf value: 0.569387794
Leaf value: 0.597284317
Leaf value: 0.581538498
Leaf value: 0.414893627
Leaf value: 0.473684251
Leaf value: 0.547826111
Leaf value: 0.566037774
Leaf value: -0.185840726
Leaf value: 0.137142867
Leaf value: -0.0962457359
Leaf value: -0.105882362
Leaf value: 0.0352941193
Leaf value: -0.180000007
Leaf value: 0.197202817
Leaf value: -0.144827589
Leaf value: -0.160714284
Leaf value: -0.169811323
Leaf value: -0.139042303
Leaf value: -0.172117963
Leaf value: -0.145945951
Leaf value: 0.16097562
Leaf value: -0.195500389
Leaf value: 0.0193548389
Leaf value: 0.120000005
Leaf value: -0.192814916
Leaf value: 0.0591549315
Leaf value: -0.0439024381
Leaf value: 0.0230769254
Leaf to class mapping:
Leaf value: 0.584565938 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.164601773 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.332342029 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.594339609 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.569387794 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.597284317 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.581538498 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.414893627 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.473684251 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.547826111 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.566037774 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.185840726 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.137142867 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.0962457359 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.105882362 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.0352941193 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.180000007 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.197202817 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.144827589 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.160714284 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.169811323 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.139042303 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.172117963 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.145945951 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.16097562 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.195500389 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.0193548389 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.120000005 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.192814916 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.0591549315 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: -0.0439024381 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor
Leaf value: 0.0230769254 -> Class: OnlyForcedLabor

